# Need to change name of a key in a script that returns a sorted List

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code that loops thru a flat json doc and creates a hierarchal of the items based on level and position. It all works as expected but i have the need to change the child elements name from child to items. And thats where my problem starts. There is 2 porions in code where i set the child:

```
   newparent = {
          ...oldparent,
          child: mItems
        };
      } else {
        newparent = {
          ...oldparent,
          child: [child]
```

So I tried to change that to items but that does not work, when i change it, I get the items key on the initial items but not for any additional items under that parent.

Here is also link to a working sample [Replit Testbed](https://replit.com/@NoSoup4you2/Hierarchy-Fix#index.js)

My Sample Output

```
[
  {
    enabled: true,
    guid: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
    level: 0,
    name: 'Farms',
    parent: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
    position: 0,
    umid: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
    child: [
      {
        enabled: true,
        guid: '144C0989-9938-4AEC-8487-094C23A5F150',
        level: 1,
        name: 'New Farm List',
        parent: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
        position: 0,
        umid: '144C0989-9938-4AEC-8487-094C23A5F150'
      },
      {
        enabled: true,
        guid: '8FBA7B0B-566E-47CD-885B-1C08B57F34F6',
        level: 1,
        name: 'Farm Lists',
        parent: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
        position: 1,
        umid: '8FBA7B0B-566E-47CD-885B-1C08B57F34F6'
      },
      {
        enabled: true,
        guid: 'FCD36DBD-0639-4856-A609-549BB10BEC1A',
        level: 1,
        name: 'Farm Upload',
        parent: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
        position: 4,
        umid: 'FCD36DBD-0639-4856-A609-549BB10BEC1A'
      },
      {
        enabled: true,
        guid: '4264DA98-1295-4A65-97C6-313485744B4D',
        level: 1,
        name: 'Campaign',
        parent: 'F56AAC06-D2EB-4E1C-B84D-25F72973312E',
        position: 4,
        umid: '4264DA98-1295-4A65-97C6-313485744B4D',
        child: [
          {
            enabled: true,
            guid: '9CBDC6BB-5B3D-4F53-B846-AFE55F34C1E9',
            level: 2,
            name: 'New Campaign',
            parent: '4264DA98-1295-4A65-97C6-313485744B4D',
            position: 5,
            umid: '9CBDC6BB-5B3D-4F53-B846-AFE55F34C1E9'
          },
          {
            enabled: true,
            guid: '281490B5-C67D-4238-9D52-DE1DFA373418',
            level: 2,
            name: 'Campaign List',
            parent: '4264DA98-1295-4A65-97C6-313485744B4D',
            position: 6,
            umid: '281490B5-C67D-4238-9D52-DE1DFA373418'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my Code

```
function menu_sorted(input) {
   
  let max_level = 0;
  var sorted_by_level = {};

  input.forEach(i => {
    if (sorted_by_level.hasOwnProperty("level_" + i.level.toString())) {
      sorted_by_level["level_" + i.level.toString()].push(i);
    } else {
      sorted_by_level["level_" + i.level.toString()] = [i];
      if (i.level > max_level) {
        max_level = i.level;
      }
    }
  });


  for (level = max_level; level > 0; level--) {
    sorted_by_level["level_" + level.toString()].forEach(child => {
      const oldparent = sorted_by_level[
        "level_" + (level - 1).toString()
      ].filter(p => p.guid === child.parent)[0];
      const parentIndex = sorted_by_level[
        "level_" + (level - 1).toString()
      ].findIndex(p => p.guid === child.parent);
      let newparent;

     // delete child.guid;
     // delete child.parent;
      if (oldparent.hasOwnProperty("child") && oldparent.child) {
        var mItems = [...oldparent.child, child];
        mItems.sort((a, b) => (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : -1);
        newparent = {
          ...oldparent,
          child: mItems
        };
      } else {
        newparent = {
          ...oldparent,
          child: [child]
        };
      }
      sorted_by_level["level_" + (level - 1).toString()][
        parentIndex
      ] = newparent;
    });
  }
  sorted_by_level.level_0.sort((a, b) => (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : -1);
  return sorted_by_level.level_0
}

console.log(util.inspect(menu_sorted(mydata.nofilter),false,null,true))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my fork of your Replit:

https://replit.com/join/wleqdijkot-mattsenne

There are additional places you need to change "child" to "items", including lines 34, 35:

```
if (oldparent.hasOwnProperty("items") && oldparent.items) {
   var mItems = [...oldparent.items, child];
```

Also the 2 changes you noted above.  Note that we don't change the local 'child' variable, but every reference to 'items' being a property needs to accounted for as well.

Comment: I was wondering at which part of the code i could delete keys from the Parent / level 0, i know how to delete them from the child part but cant find the right place for the parent.